# Getting values from a table based on Session data

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I have an admin section to one of my websites I am building.

The variables it logs in by is email address and password.

Obviously each email address is unique to each admin, although I do have an 'admin_id' column which increments automatically per row.

The other columns stored within my admin table are - First Name (String), Last Name(String), Level(int).

I have tried -

```
$_SESSION['admin_id']=$_GET['admin_id'];
```

But when I try and simply echo the id, nothing is displayed.

Yet this line of code:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['admin_email'])) 
die("<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=login.php'> ");
```

Manages to get the 'Admin_email' column from the table.

I am confused as to how to add other columns into my session data.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You have remembered to call `session_start()` before `$_SESSION['admin_id']=$_GET['admin_id'];` and there is actually a value in `$_GET['admin_id']` ??

Comment: Yes session_start(); is on the second line, just after <?php - And there should be a value '2' in there, as this on the same row as the email address i've used to log in.

Comment: How are you "getting" the id/email? Does the script that runs the MySQL query redirect to a URL that includes them? Or you're AJAXing it and setting the session based on the data returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out why the 'admin_id' was not successful in been retrieved from the database.

The login.php where the admin first must authenticate themselves from is where the session data is saved - for it to be used in the admin session once logged in.

In order to solve this, I added the following line within the login.php (whilst the email address were been retrieved from the database):

```
$dblevel = $row['level'];
```

and then to save it to a session:

```
$_SESSION['admin_level']=$dblevel;
```

I logged out and then back in to reinitiate the session and it worked.